# Spatie / Permissions throwing constraint failure when assigning Roles using UUID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 9 project where I am using UUID's. I have just installed the Spatie Permissions package and followed the instructions to use it with UUID's ... But when I try to `assignRole` I am getting the following error;

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`model_has_roles`, CONSTRAINT `model_has_roles_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `model_has_roles` (`model_id`, `model_type`, `role_id`) values (1d6535d1-01f0-43b4-8701-4e3c76ad1587, App\Models\User, 0))
```

I think it might be something to do with the Spatie migration which comes with the package. I have updated it as per `https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/advanced-usage/uuid#content-migrations` .. as below;

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar;

class CreatePermissionTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $tableNames = config('permission.table_names');
        $columnNames = config('permission.column_names');
        $teams = config('permission.teams');

        if (empty($tableNames)) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: config/permission.php not loaded. Run [php artisan config:clear] and try again.');
        }
        if ($teams && empty($columnNames['team_foreign_key'] ?? null)) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: team_foreign_key on config/permission.php not loaded. Run [php artisan config:clear] and try again.');
        }

        Schema::create($tableNames['permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id'); // permission id
            $table->string('name');       // For MySQL 8.0 use string('name', 125);
            $table->string('guard_name'); // For MySQL 8.0 use string('guard_name', 125);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('id');

            $table->unique(['name', 'guard_name']);
        });

        Schema::create($tableNames['roles'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($teams, $columnNames) {
            $table->uuid('id'); // role id
            if ($teams || config('permission.testing')) { // permission.testing is a fix for sqlite testing
                $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['team_foreign_key'])->nullable();
                $table->index($columnNames['team_foreign_key'], 'roles_team_foreign_key_index');
            }
            $table->string('name');       // For MySQL 8.0 use string('name', 125);
            $table->string('guard_name'); // For MySQL 8.0 use string('guard_name', 125);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('id');

            if ($teams || config('permission.testing')) {
                $table->unique([$columnNames['team_foreign_key'], 'name', 'guard_name']);
            } else {
                $table->unique(['name', 'guard_name']);
            }
        });

        Schema::create($tableNames['model_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames, $columnNames, $teams) {
            $table->uuid(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission);

            $table->string('model_type');
            $table->uuid($columnNames['model_morph_key']);
            $table->index([$columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'], 'model_has_permissions_model_id_model_type_index');

            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission)
                ->references('id') // permission id
                ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            if ($teams) {
                $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['team_foreign_key']);
                $table->index($columnNames['team_foreign_key'], 'model_has_permissions_team_foreign_key_index');

                $table->primary([$columnNames['team_foreign_key'], PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission, $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                    'model_has_permissions_permission_model_type_primary');
            } else {
                $table->primary([PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission, $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                    'model_has_permissions_permission_model_type_primary');
            }

        });

        Schema::create($tableNames['model_has_roles'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames, $columnNames, $teams) {
            $table->uuid(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole);

            $table->string('model_type');
            $table->uuid($columnNames['model_morph_key']);
            $table->index([$columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'], 'model_has_roles_model_id_model_type_index');

            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole)
                ->references('id') // role id
                ->on($tableNames['roles'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            if ($teams) {
                $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['team_foreign_key']);
                $table->index($columnNames['team_foreign_key'], 'model_has_roles_team_foreign_key_index');

                $table->primary([$columnNames['team_foreign_key'], PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole, $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                    'model_has_roles_role_model_type_primary');
            } else {
                $table->primary([PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole, $columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'],
                    'model_has_roles_role_model_type_primary');
            }
        });

        Schema::create($tableNames['role_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames) {
            $table->uuid(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission);
            $table->uuid(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole);

            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission)
                ->references('id') // permission id
                ->on($tableNames['permissions'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole)
                ->references('id') // role id
                ->on($tableNames['roles'])
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary([PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission, PermissionRegistrar::$pivotRole], 'role_has_permissions_permission_id_role_id_primary');
        });

        app('cache')
            ->store(config('permission.cache.store') != 'default' ? config('permission.cache.store') : null)
            ->forget(config('permission.cache.key'));
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $tableNames = config('permission.table_names');

        if (empty($tableNames)) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: config/permission.php not found and defaults could not be merged. Please publish the package configuration before proceeding, or drop the tables manually.');
        }

        Schema::drop($tableNames['role_has_permissions']);
        Schema::drop($tableNames['model_has_roles']);
        Schema::drop($tableNames['model_has_permissions']);
        Schema::drop($tableNames['roles']);
        Schema::drop($tableNames['permissions']);
    }
}
```

I have a trait for UUID which is as follows;

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait HasUuid
{
    protected static function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
            }
        });
    }

    public function getIncrementing(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getKeyType(): string
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

I have this on my User model, and also I have extended the `Role` and `Permission` model which now looks like this;

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use App\Concerns\HasUuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;

class Role extends SpatieRole
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasUuid;
}
```

The code that it is failing on is the following which is a standard user create, but the `assignRole` is where it seems to be failing;

```php
User::create([
    'name' => 'Super Admin',
    'email' => 'super-admin@example.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
])->assignRole('super-admin');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure this out if anyone has the same issue.

As I am extending the `Role` and `Permission` model, this needs to be reflected in the `config/permission.php` file

```
    'models' => [

        /*
         * When using the "HasPermissions" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your permissions. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Permission" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Permission model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` contract.
         */

        'permission' => \App\Models\Permission::class,

        /*
         * When using the "HasRoles" trait from this package, we need to know which
         * Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your roles. Of course, it
         * is often just the "Role" model but you may use whatever you like.
         *
         * The model you want to use as a Role model needs to implement the
         * `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role` contract.
         */

        'role' => \App\Models\Role::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Yep fixed it for me too! I didn't see this in the docs on the Spatie site... thanks mate, much appreciated on a fresh project - I always forget about this stuff because you only set it up once and never touch for years.

Comment: You saved my weekend!